# Weather station data

Tags: wind, open-data, field-measurements, weatherdata

I am currently setting up a wind-wave model for which I need to input the wind forcing for the whole domain.

I have obtained the wind speed and direction from two sources: CFSv2 and ERA5. Unfortunately, I found some discrepancies between the two datasets.

To select the most suitable dataset for my case I am trying to compare the datasets values to the field measurement. So, Where I can find wind measurements from weather stations online?

I am interested in the Mediterranean zone and I need the hourly data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do a model skill assessment, then the best way is to try to use observations that have a similar footprint to the model. I would recommend you try remote sensed data. A good place to begin is [here](https://www.remss.com/measurements/wind/). If you are looking for observations at a point in the Mediterranean, you can try in Copernicus. If you are a registered user of ECMWF products, you can the [Meteorological Archival and Retrieval System (MARS)](https://apps.ecmwf.int/mars-catalogue/).

Comment: I am a registered user of ECMWF but I don't have access to MARS. Can you provide a link for in-situ observations product through Copernicus?

Comment: Try the email in https://www.efas.eu/en/data-download

Comment: Also check: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/COPSRV/MARS+archive